# Gridview generate extra column on left

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using asp.net c#.I have following code this code is working fine.But problem is gridview generate one extra column on left.

```
<asp:GridView Width="96%" CssClass="grdclass" ID="grd" 
   runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="STAT_ID">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC99" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <th scope="col">الهاتف</th>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <td class="row_style">
                        <div class="row_style">
                            <%#Eval("PHONE_Num") %>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>No Record Found</EmptyDataTemplate>
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Aquamarine" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Please check above code and guide me where is the mistake or how can I get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put table element definitions inside a grid view, do like this:

```
          <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        الهاتف
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="row_style">
                            <%#Eval("PHONE_Num") %>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
```

Comment: i have more than one column

Comment: No problem, you can add a new asp:TemplateField to the Grid.

Comment: i have more than one column

Comment: i  want  custom  header.In which i put colspan

Comment: I will also put sub headers

Comment: How can i put sub header in it

Comment: Two template field one header

Comment: You probably don't have to use a GridView but a repeater that is more flexible and leave you the freedom to do whatever you want with HTML.

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods to create a `GridView` with subheaders. But, with the introduction of `ListView`, most of the methods are a bit of overkill. Try using a `ListView` like this.

```
<asp:ListView ID="CustomersList" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table class="grdclass">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">Phone Numbers</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Home</th>
                    <th>Mobile</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr id="itemplaceholder" runat="server"></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%# Eval("PHONE_Num") %></td>
            <td><%# Eval("MOBILE_Num") %></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

`ListView` gives you much more control over your html markup.